# Visual Studio Tools for Git pushes to the wrong branch

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, github

On GitHub's site, I created a branch similarly named to dev--foo-bar#123. In Visual Studio I checked out that branch and made a commit to it. When I pushed the changes, it pushed to a new branch called dev--foo-bar (without the #123).

Is there some reason Visual Studio cannot handle a branch name with a '#' character? I wanted to work with waffle.io, which uses this naming convention.

Answer (score 1):

I found this [interesting article](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/2284) about the ZSH plugin for Git which appears to be very similar to the problem you are currently experiencing.

> The '#' character is used in ZSH for pattern removal. To create a git branch with it, surround the branch name with quotes to stop ZSH from parsing the string. For example, git branch 'branch#213'

I believe that when you attempted to create a Git branch called `dev--foo-bar#123`, the `#123` portion was interpreted as some some of filter and was not actually treated as part of the branch name.  In other words, the name of the local branch which you pushed is actually `dev--foo-bar`, which is consistent with what you observed appearing in GitHub.

To remedy this, next time you create a numbered branch, try placing the branch name into single quotes, e.g. use the following

```
'dev--foo-bar#123'
```

Comment: The single quotes ended up just pushing out a branch name in quotes, which doesn't work for me. I believe you are probably correct about the reasoning why the #123 is dropped, though. I am currently just using the command line to push branches with this naming convention, instead.